# How to calculate cumulative effect of variable in a regression?

Tags: regression, lm, lme4

I have run a regression and my explanatory variable has a beta coefficient of -0.016 and a standard error of 0.006.
This variable ranges from 7 to 11.
How can I estimate the cumulative effect that going from 7 to 11 will have on the dependent variable?

Comment: Not sure if this question fits StackOverflow, which is more about programming. Nevertheless, what type of regression is it, linear? And what is "cumulative effect"?

Comment: Basically, I wanted to know the predicted effect (with 95% confidence intervals) that going from 7 to 11 in the IV would have on the DV. This worked with the ggpredict() function

Comment: It seems then the you have solved the problem with `ggpredict()`. For future reference, please post this here as an answer.